# find identify to deduce

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a long text, with spaces and hyphens. I have a line  it is in the middle of the text, I need to detect the value after the colon and output it to the console, how can I do this?

example:

```
become aware of happiness once you have lost it.
Then an age comes, a second one, in which you already know, at the moment when you begin to experience true happiness, that you are, at the end of the day, going to lose it.
When I met Belle, I understood that I had just entered this second age.
SUID: va1u3.
I also understood that I hadn’t reached the third age, in which anticipation of the loss of happiness prevents you from living.
```

I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: we neither, unless you tell us what makes that particular line special.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.